# In the Catholic Church, other than cardinals, are there any other prelates that may don red cassocks?

Tags: catholicism, clergy, clothing

In the Catholic Church, the clerical dress (cassock) of cardinals is scarlet red in color. Are there any other catholic prelates who may don red cassocks?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.

The Archbishops of certain sees are entitled to wear red ex officio, whether or not they are cardinals.

The Patriarch of [Venice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patriarch_of_Venice) has this right, as do the occupants  of  sees holding  [legatus natus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Papal_legate) (born legates, or legates as of right) status. Archbishops of these sees have the right to wear red. These include  [Salzburg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Franz_Lackner),  [Udine](http://orbiscatholicussecundus.blogspot.co.uk/2009/10/bishops-who-wear-red.html), Cologne and [Poznan](http://everything.explained.today/J%C3%B3zef_Glemp/).

Prior to the Reformation, Canterbury was a legatus natus see.

Answer (score 0):

Primates of some countries also have the privilege of wearing cardinal red, but that excludes the zucchetto, which is still to be the traditional bishop purple